# How to remove Devise oAuth Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, twitter-oauth

I am trying to remove Oauth twitter (we are keeping facebook). I've removed all references, but I'm still getting this error from the devise signup controller (I basically used the tutorial to remove or comment out all of the twitter specific code:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users/omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>:twitter}
```

I suspect that there was something installed with the oauth-twitter gem that I haven't been able to easily remove.

Comment: At what point do you get the error?

Comment: When I try to go to the login or register screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the following route in routes.rb?

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

Comment: Yes. Is there something I can do to make it only look at facebook? Presumably there's some place in Devise where it's remembering that I had twitter setup and not being able to find the code that I removed to process twitter logins.

Comment: look in config/initializers/devise.rb and make sure you don't have anything like this: config.omniauth :twitter, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo'

Comment: I commented twitter out in config/initializers/devise.rb

Comment: Do you have a login link anywhere that looks like this:  <%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had html commented them out <!-- --> but of course Ruby is going to still try to render them.